# Duple select from database in same table but diffent proposes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First option of select must be the name referring to the ID. The remaining select options are the remaining names

```
<select class="input" name="client_id">
  <?php
  $sel_client_detail="Select * from client WHERE client_id=".$id."";
  $result_detail = mysqli_query($con,$sel_client_detail);

  while($new_record_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_detail)) { ?>
    <option selected><?php echo $row['nome'];?></option>
  <?php };?>

  <?php
  $sel_client="Select * from client";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_client);
  ?>
  <option>-----------</option>

  <?php while($new_record_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <option><?php echo $new_record_row['nome'];?></option>
  <?php };?>
</select>
```

Output:

```
<select>
<option selected> Izzi (current ID name)</option> 
<option> ____________</option> 
<option> Other existing clients</option>
<option> Other existing clients</option>
<option> Other existing clients</option>
<option> Other existing clients</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: why 2 queries? You can handle everything with only 1 query

Comment: NOTE if a query will only return One row in the result set you dont need a while loop to fetch that one row

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different, but more conventional, approach to this common scenario:

Why not just make the chosen ID `selected` when you get to it in the list? Then it will still show to the user first. It's more efficient than having two separate queries.

Like this:

```
<select class="input" name="client_id">
  <?php
  $sel_client="Select * from client";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_client);
  ?>
  <option>-----------</option>

  <?php while($new_record_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <option <?php echo ($new_record_row["client_id"] == $id ? "selected": ""); ?> ><?php echo $new_record_row['nome'];?></option>
  <?php };?>
</select>
```

Comment: Missing "echo" between "<?php" and "($new_record_row["client_id"] == $id ? ..."

Comment: @Mystral so there is, thanks. Have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be first in your option list just run the query once and build the HTML parts in 2 seperate strings. Then once the loop is complete put them together and echo them

```
<?php

echo '<select class="input" name="client_id">';

$itsme = '';
$others = '<option>-----------</option>';

$sql = "Select * from client";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if ( $id == $row['id'] ) {
        $itsme = "<option selected='selected'>$new_record_row[nome]</option>";
    } else {
        $others += "<option>$new_record_row[nome]</option>";
    }
}
// put the option tags together in the order you specified

echo $itsme . $others . '</select>';
```

Comment: With `selected=\"selected\"` escaped though since it's inside a `"string"`.

Comment: @MarkusAO No using a `'` instead, much easier :) Thanks for the nudge

Comment: Even just `<option selected>` would do really. I grew up with XHTML so anything but `"` still makes me twitch.